# I can't access the website project in the folder www on wamp

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp

I am building a website using wordpress on local WAMP. Already running perfect when I go through the server computer. But, when trying to access from other device that are connected on the network LAN, it work. but, the browser brings up a text link without border, background, images etc on my project.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are setting the URLs as http://localhost,

try changing all links to your machine's IP address.

http://192.168.1.101 for example

*Edit*

The browser only shows texts with no styles because it fails to load the assets,
and that's because you are setting the base URL to localhost.

Comment: it working, thanks bro!

Comment: @HanndyDannovan You are welcome, if you found my answer helpful, feel free to mark it as answered.